# Ti.Barcode Module for Android platform in Appcelerator Titanium? (Barcode Scanner)

Tags: javascript, android, module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am working with Appcelerator Titanium. I want to use `Barcode Scanner` in my app. On iOS platform, I found a module `"Ti.Barcode-iPhone"` open source. But, I want it for both **Android and iOS platform**. Where will I find it?

Answer (score 2):

There are official modules by Appcelerator: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.barcode

Download the releases (there also is one for TiSDK 7.x) you need and then include them in `tiapp.xml` and then include easily:

```
var Barcode = require('ti.barcode');
```

Examples how to include are listed in the example directory per platform, like this one: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.barcode/blob/master/android/example/app.js

Comment: Thanks bro! I have downloaded the Zip file. Extracted it. Two folder is there one for Android and other iOS. Can you please tell how i integrate this as a module and use it anywhere from my app like this-  var Barcode = require('ti.barcode');

Comment: put the modules folder in the root of your application. So on same level as tiapp.xml

Comment: NO. It didn't work! I put modules folder at root folder of the app. And installed by help>install mobile module> installed module and it appeared in module section. But when I importing that module into my project. ex- var barcode =  require("ti.barcode"); error came MODULE NOT FOUND. what i do now?

Comment: I am using Titanium SDK 7.2.0 GA. For this version of SDK, Is there any barcode module for android platform? Thanks for reply bro.

Comment: yep that module is just available @DeepakVerma